# functionality required only to show certificate(image) for registered members

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I want to junrate a certificate(image) general code from my site registers members certificate will only show on his sites.for exmple abc.com is my registerd member and he placed that code on his site like bellow

```
img src="mysite.com?member=abc.com"
```

or any code (like facebook social plugin  or like plugin of facebook etc)
when its calling from abc.com the code will display the certificate(image) but when same code applies to another location like www.def.com the certificate(image) should not to display.

Comment: I'm guessing that "junrate" is intended to be, "generate".

Answer (score 2):

You might want to do something like this:

1 Create a php file on your server called certificate.php

2 Allow your users to access it like this: `<img src="http://www.yoursite.com/certificate.php?member=abc.com" />`

3 Check the $_SERVER variable for HTTP_REFERER

4 See if that HTTP_REFERER contains the correct domain (abc.com)

5 Show/or don't show the image

```
$member = $_GET['member']; // Validate this field against an allowed list before continuing   
$referal = parse_url($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
$hostname = str_replace('www.', '', $referal['hostname']); // Remove www. part

if ($hostname == $member)
{
    // This request is coming from an abc.com website
}
else
{
    // I don't this think is coming from abc.com website
}
```

Comment: I would think you would want to look at the Referer instead. But I'm assuming the way this is supposed to work is, an end user hits abc.com, abc.com returns a page that refers to the image on mysite.com, and mysite.com returns either the certificate image, or a goatse image, or whatever.

Comment: Referals can be spoofed by modifying the header data in the request. REMOTE_ADDR can't, since it's the IP address the response is sent back to.

Comment: But the REMOTE_ADDR wouldn't contain the right information to validate. The REMOTE_ADDR is just the IP address of J. Random User's computer. The way I understand the question, the OP wants abc.com to be able to embed this in a web page ("he placed that code on his site"). So abc.com is not fetching the image from mysite.com. Even though the Referer header can be spoofed, I think it's what he's looking for.

Comment: Ah quite true. Obviously not enough coffee this side. I'll modify the code to use the HTTP_REFERER instead.

Comment: The question was rather confusing. I'm guessing at the intent, myself. Cheers.

Comment: Ok thanks guys, I have got the answer how to do it... very thanks to all